# force component to rerender

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using react hooks for the first time, when I click on delete button I need to refresh the page in order to see that the item has been deleted , how can I make the component re-render right after the delete api call ?

```
 function Component(){
        const [data, setData] = useState({ contact: [] });

        useEffect(() => {
          const fetchData = async () => {
          const result = await axios("url");
          setData(result.data);
        };
        fetchData();
      }, [props])
        async function handleDelete(id) {
            try {
                await axios(`anotherurl`);
             }  catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
             }
           }
        return(
            data.contact.map(contact => (
                <li key={contact._id} >
                <p> contact.name</p>
                <button onClick={()=>handleDelete(contact._id)}>
                delete
                </button>    
                </li>
              ))
         )
        }
```

Comment: What are the results of the `delete` call? I mean, deleting it on the back end won't change your local state unless that's how it's written (unclear if the snippet provided is complete).

Comment: @DaveNewton the backend is working I mean on the front it does not show that the item I cliked the deleted button on is deleted until I refresh the page and a new fetch via useEffect is triggred (not showing on snippet)

Comment: Why would it? All you did was delete it on the back end--this won't magically update your client's state unless you explicitly code it to, either by removing it in your state, or by delete returning the same query (which would reflect the now-deleted item) or etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `useState` hook: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

`useState` is similar to `setState`. When a new value is passed to `useState(newValue)`, the component will re-render

Hopefully this answers your question!

Comment: I did use useState

Comment: @randomdreamer ic, your code was edited when I looked at it last time...

After you call `handleDelete`, I didn't see anywhere you called `setState` to update the local data?

Answer (score -1):

There is a dirty alternative(not recommend):

```
this.forceUpdate();
```

Comment: @randomdreamer Unlikely to not work--it's just that you're expecting something to happen that you have not coded to happen.